projectileEntity.setProperties(player, player.getPitch(), player.yaw, 0.0F, 3.0F, 1.0F);
setProperties is error!
player.yaw what yaw should i use?
Make Projectile Entity from Item
                       ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd                                                                                                             


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

player.yaw is a Private variable.
You can use player.getYaw() instead.
